# Dafny collect evens below N

Tags: formal-verification, dafny

Here's an example which takes an integer `lim` and returns a sequence of all integers strictly less than `lim` which are even.

Only the backward direction of the `... <==> ...` in the second invariant does not verify. I have tried playing around with this for a while and I haven't been able to figure it out.

Any help is much appreciated!

```
method evens(lim : int) returns (ret : seq<int>)
  requires 0 < lim
{
  ret := [];

  var i := 0;

  while (i < lim)
    invariant 0 <= i <= lim
    invariant forall idx :: 0 <= idx < i ==> (idx % 2 == 0 <==> idx in ret)
  {
    if (i % 2 == 0) {
      ret := [i] + ret;
    }

    i := i + 1;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add this invariant:

```
invariant forall idx :: idx in ret ==> idx % 2 == 0
```

It implies that all the members in the `ret` array are divisible by 2.
The invariant

`invariant forall idx :: 0 <= idx < i ==> (idx in ret ==> idx % 2 == 0)`

is failing because `ret` might contain members for whom the condition `0 <= idx < i` is true but they might not be divisible by 2. Consider this code: http://www.rise4fun.com/Dafny/W7RwL